# Ftp backup folder download as files,, i cant find .tar.gz files

Tags: linux, ftp, backup

i create backup folder in ftp server , and send all my .tar.gz file into /backup folder

using (put file.tar.gz backup)

while i retrieve backup,, i get backup folder as backup files. ,, how to convert the file to folder ..

ftp server

`ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,21,131,105,76,56)
150 Accepted data connection
drwxr-xr-x    6 100        ftpgroup            7 Oct 20 19:57 .
drwxr-xr-x    6 100        ftpgroup            7 Oct 20 19:57 ..
-r--------    1 100        ftpgroup           84 Oct 21 11:15 .banner
drwxrwxrwx    3 100        ftpgroup            4 Oct 20 18:28 backup
drwxrwxrwx    2 100        ftpgroup            3 Oct 20 19:45 dailybackup
drwxrwxr-x    2 100        ftpgroup            3 Oct 20 19:57 hi5songs
drwxrwxr-x    2 100        ftpgroup            3 Oct 20 19:49 whole
226-Options: -a -l
226 7 matches total`

i tried :

ftp> ``` mget backup``
mget .? y
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,21,131,105,62,8)
550 I can only retrieve regular files
mget ..? y
Warning: embedded .. in .. (changing to !!)
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,21,131,105,46,39)
550 Can't open !!: No such file or directory
mget backup? y
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,21,131,105,72,24)
550 I can only retrieve regular files
mget cpanelbackup? y
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,21,131,105,73,69)
550 Can't open cpanelbackup: No such file or directory ```

while
 i use (get backup home) 
 it successfully retrieve but as files shown below

server:
 `'root@azar [/home]# ls
./                               backup.2*  .cpan/          dailybackup  hi5songs.4   oldeserver
../                              backup.3*  cPanelInstall/  hi5songs/    hi5songs.5   oldserver/
0_README_BEFORE_DELETING_VIRTFS  backup.4*  .cpanm/         hi5songs.1   home         quota.user
backup/                          backup.5*  .cpcpan/        hi5songs.2   latest       virtfs/
backup.1*                        .banner    cpeasyapache/   hi5songs.3   lost+found/  whole'`

i got that backup with green color executable file like backup.1* ( note: i cant open those file and extract those files) what to do
how to get my .tar.gz file back

please guide me,,

advance thanks,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to get all files from `/some/place` on your server, to `/home/here` on your local machine, you would either do this:

```
cd /home/here      # change directory before starting FTP
ftp server ...     # connect
cd /some/place     # go to desired folder on server
bi                 # ensure no funny business with line-endings
mget *             # get all files
```

or you can change directory locally, within FTP like this:

```
ftp server ...     # connect
cd /some/place     # go to desired folder on server
lcd /home/here     # LOCALLY change directory to where you want the files to 'land'
bi                 # ensure no funny business
mget *             # get all files
```

**Original Answer**

I cannot understand your question at all, but you are doing some things wrong.

1. You cannot use `GET` or `MGET` to get a folder (directory) like you are trying to do with `mget backup`. You can only `GET` a file. Now your file may be a tar-file with more than one file in it, but it is still a file.
2. If you are getting tar-files and binary files, you should use `BINARY` mode to ensure line-end characters that may occur in binary files are not translated between Windows and Unix line-endings. So, as a matter of course, you should issue `BI` command before you get files.
3. If you have several files in your `backup` directory, you should probably do `cd backup` then `bi`
   then `mget *`

Comment: sry for bad english,, ohh than how to get a whole folder from ftp server or how to view files inside folder in ftp .. i cant view files inside folder

Comment: `cd backup` then `ls` or `dir`

Comment: how to get whole backup folder to local : home directory